How to describe the structure in ctypes
I have the following code in my header file:
typedef struct {
      void *Handle;
} RESHANDLE, *PRESHANDLE;

How do I describe the structure in ctypes (Python)?

Voting to reopen this question because Mark Tolonen's answer shows that it provided all the information necessary to be answered.

Derive structures from ctypes.Structure and declare the structure member names and types as shown:
import ctypes as ct

class RESHANDLE(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ('Handle', ct.c_void_p),

PRESHANDLE = ct.POINTER(RESHANDLE)

See Structures and unions in the ctypes documentation.
